# hide panel based on grid view row selection in same page on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have below GridView with radio button as column. I want to hide or display panel based on GridView row selection that will be rendering outside of GridView in same page.

Below is my GridView:

```
<table style="width: 95%; margin-top: 10px;" class="transferCertsTbl">
  <tr style="width: 95%">
      <td colspan="2">
          <asp:GridView ID="gvClearpassCertInfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
              CellSpacing="1" CellPadding="1"
              Width="95%" BorderWidth="0"
              AllowSorting="True"
              PageSize="30"
              OnRowDataBound="gvClearpassCertInfo_RowDataBound"
              CssClass="data responsive">
              <Columns>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" SortExpression="">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:RadioButton ID="radioChkCert" runat="server" onclick="RadioCheck(this);" /><input type="hidden" id="hdnCertId" runat="server" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CertId") %>' />
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="CertificateID" HeaderText="Certificate ID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="partID" HeaderText="Part Number"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="BaseLicense" HeaderText="Base License" Visible="false" />
              </Columns>
              <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" />
              <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              <AlternatingRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              <PagerSettings Visible="False" />
          </asp:GridView>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I am not sure how to display or hide based on row selection in GridView on server side only.

Could any one please help on this that would be very grateful to me?

Comment: your wanted gridview row is selected by the radiobtn?

Comment: i am able to select the radion button inside gridview but  based on selection i need to hide the panel..

Comment: please check the answer i posted

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- For the radio button tag add autopostback=true and OnCheckedChanged="radioChkCert_CheckedChanged" like this:

  ```
  <asp:RadioButton ID="radioChkCert" runat="server" onclick="RadioCheck(this);" autopostback="true" OnCheckedChanged="radioChkCert_CheckedChanged"/>
  ```
- in the codebehind add the function:

  ```
    protected void radioChkCert_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   radiobutton radiobtn = (radiobutton)sender;

   string txt = (((Label)radiobtn.Parent.FindControl("l1")).Text); //l1 is the id of a label in the gridview

   if ((txt == "CertainCode")) {
      Certainpanel.Visible = true;
  }


  }
  ```

### Note:

I used the label's text to control which panel to show, in your case choose it depending on which control and it's value.
I converted from vb.net to C# tell me if there is an error